# Unable to reduce iframe size in ios7

Tags: iframe, ios7, safari

In IOS7 (Safari) we are seeing an issue where the iframe will not accept a lower width/height. For example, on an orientation change event the new width maybe say 600 vs 320. While it will resize to 600, going back to portrait mode, the width will remain at 600 instead of resetting back to 320. We have confirmed the values are being set correctly within the attributes of the iframe, but the css values are remaining at the previous larger values. We've tried clearing the style attribute altogether, resetting the dimensions to 0 directly before setting the new values, etc. Nothing seems to take affect. I'm leaning toward believing this is a safari bug. Has anyone else experienced this? All of the other posts that are similar all seem to be reporting scrolling issues and not resizing issues.

Comment: How are you setting the width of the iFrame? you should just be able to put a percentage width on it.

Comment: I tried just about everything I could think of but the solution I'm using it setting the size of the inner content first via postMessage and then resizing the iframe - however the content at least in my case, had to be slightly less than 100%. Setting it to 100% was causing it to somehow double in side even though calculated with/height was the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

IOS will show all visible content, so you can't hide the overflow of an iframe. Is your content wider than the iframe? I have a feeling it might be